Wi-Fi adapter Edimax EW-7811UTC does not work with higher channels in the 5 GHz band
On my system lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS I use the wireless adapter Edimax EW-7811UTC to connect to Wi-Fi Networks.
Ok at 2.4 GHz band
The adapter works correcty for the 2.4 GHz band (I don't have tested all the channels, but with this band I haven't had any problems until now).
Some problem at 5 GHz band
Instead I have verified that the adapter doesn't work with some channels of the 5 GHz band.
To be more accurate I have tested that it works for the following channels:

36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64 (Edimax EW-7811UTC Works!)

while it doesn't work with the following channels:

100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 132, 136 (Edimax EW-7811UTC doesn't works!)

To exclude some problem on the software driver installed on lubuntu, I have tested the adapter in a Windows 11 system with a driver written in 2022, and also in this system the results of the tests have been the same of those on lubuntu.
The frequency of the channels
At this link on wikipedia I have found the frequency range of all the channels of the 5GHz band. With these frequencies in mind I have consulted the datasheet of the adapter where it is written:

Frequency Band
• 2.4 GHz: 2.4000~2.4835 GHz
• 5 GHz: 5.150~5.825 GHz
*Subject to local regulations.

Because the frequency of the channel 100 is 5.490~5.510 GHz and the frequency of the channel 136 is 5.670~5.690 GHz that is less than 5.825 GHz written in the datasheet, I thought the adapter worked for both channels and with all the channels that I have tested.
Find the channel frequencies with iwlist and sub-command freq
If I execute the command iwlist on a terminal, I obtain the following output:
> iwlist <wifi-adapter-name> freq
<wifi-adapter-name>  21 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

This is compliant with my empirical tests.
In this post I have found an execution of the command iwlist which is similar to mine but the answer of that question is not exhaustive for me.
Note. iwlist is installed by the package wireless-tools and in this post it is possible to check if the package is installed.
Question
Could someone try to explain me why my Edimax EW-7811UTC adapter does not work on higher channels of the 5 GHz band?

If it is the same in Windows it must be because of laws in your area regulating frequency usage

I get some information about my Wi-Fi adapter EDIMAX EW-7811UTC.
Official frequency range
In my question I have written that the adapter works in the intervals frequencies 2.4000~2.4835 GHz and 5.150~5.825 GHz because I have found this information in this commercial datasheet.
After other searches, I have found this other technical datasheet of EDIMAX EW-7811UTC, where it is written that the adapter supports the following frequency intervals for the 2.4GHz band

2.4GHz Frequency range: 2400~2483.5 MHz, with a Max. Transmit
Power 17.75 dBm

While for 5 GHz band:

5 GHz Frequency range: 5150~5250 MHz, with a Max. Transmit
Power 19.68 dBm

This means that only the channels 36, 40, 44 and 48 are supported.
Note. Actually my tests show that also channel 52, 56, 60, 64 work with my access point but this is not declared by the adapter manufacturer.
Edimax do not support interval frequency for channels greater than 144
By a useful email exchange with the Edimax support I have discovered that they produce adapters that are not compatible with high channels of the 5GHz band; the higher channel, compatible with Edimax adapters, is the 144.
The channel 144 works in the interval frequencies 5710–5730 MHz; to get details about frequency channels see this link.
This is because Edimax mounts chips on its adapters that are limited by the chips vendor to the frequencies showed above.
Frequency intervals established by my regional regulations
My Edimax EW-7811UTC adapter does not work in the channel 96 (frequencies higher than 5470 MHz) due to my frequency regional regulations, just like @Jeremy31 said in his comment on my question.
The chip vendor installs a firmware on the chip mounted on EW-7811UTC which, on my region, limits the working frequencies to be less then channel 96.
By the tests, reported on my question, I have showed that the range of channels supported by my adapter are from 36 to 64 (although the official documentation reports only the range of channels 36-48) so these channels are compatible with the regional regulations of my country.
